How can I pass an expression to use in a SQLAlchemy filter or where clause around?
I am trying to reproduce a behavior from ORMs like sqlalchemy and peewee that allow to pass an entire expression as a single argument to a function. For example in sqlalchemy or in peewee that i prefer to use as a reference because the source code is a lot easier to assimilate, we can do as follow:
grandma = Person.select().where(Person.name == 'Grandma L.').get()

What i am trying to understand and reproduce is how to handle the expression provided as argument to where(), the Person.name == 'Grandma L.' part, to get it from within the function so i can convert it into an SQL statement later on.
I know i could put the expression in quotes to pass it as a one string argument but that is not very pythonic and neither peewee nor sqlalchemy had to do this. I tried to see how they do it by examining the source code and what i believe to be de where() function used for select queries but there is almost nothing in this function and i can't figure out how they handle the expression has an argument. They seem to simply have *expression as parameter which like *args accepts an unknown number of arguments. I also checked the where() function of sqlalchemy and they also somehow use the form *whereclause to receive the expression.
I know even less how to do it with complex expression like this:
query = Person.select().where((Person.birthday < d1940) | (Person.birthday > d1960)))

From what i understand after a lot of testing python will always evaluate the expression passed as argument and instead pass the result of the expression to the function, so is it possible to get the expression itself from inside the function?

How this works depends on ORM implementation details, so asking it tagged for multiple ORMs is not ideal here.

You don't need to pass "the expression itself" -- the result of evaluating the expression is an object that describes to SQLAlchemy what the filters you want to apply are. (SQLAlchemy does this by overloading <, ==, and other operators for the column objects such that instead of returning the result of a single comparison, they return an object that describes that comparison itself; from the calling convention you've shown, I assume Peewee does something similar).
Thus:
conditions = [(Person.birthday < d1940) | (Person.birthday > d1960)]

...can have the result passed around as much as you like (and can have other conditions added to the list), eventually being used as:
query = Person.select().where(*conditions)


Let's look at a runnable example:
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, Column, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, DeclarativeBase

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    ...

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    birth_year = Column(Integer)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

query_terms = [
  (Person.name == 'Grandma L.')
]
print(query_terms)

The output of that print is something like:
[<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7ffff719ba10>]

That is, it's not a specific True or False value, but an object that SQLAlchemy can later use when that object is passed to where() or similar.

By overloading operators? How do you mean? Plus if a try the conditions as you put them i don't get an object like you said but a simple list containing [True] as you can see here

@CarlL, I can't follow that link without setting up an account. Note that my statements were made about SQLAlchemy; if peewee does something different, I don't know it (and it's arguably inappropriate to use the SQLAlchemy tag on questions for which you won't accept a SQLAlchemy-only answer).

@CarlL, what I mean is that SQLAlchemy column objects have __lt__ defined as a function that overrides the default meaning of <, __gt__ defined as a function that overrides the default meaning of >, __eq__ overriding ==, etc etc. So when you're using a SQLAlchemy column object as part of an == comparison, it's not actually doing an (immediate) comparison at all, and doesn't return True. I'd need a [mre] to explain why you see any other result.

(Similarly, the returned objects override __or__ to make | return an object that tells SQLAlchemy to generate an OR clause between its two arguments when the result is later being returned to SQL)

I don't know why you say i didn't accept an answer about sqlalchemy. Your answer does absolutely not show how to handle an expression as arguments from within a function nor does it explain how sqlalchemy does it. Now when you say "SQLAlchemy column objects have __lt__ defined as a function that overrides the default meaning of <," Can you expand on that, i don't see the link with the column object. You say the returned object override __or__. This doesn't tell me how the function gets the OR from the expression in the first place. What returned object?

If you could give me runnable code, I'd run that code, define a few quick queries against it, and show you the returned object. You're not providing a [mre], and I'm not going to write one myself -- that's your job as the person asking the question. Add a complete-enough-to-run definition of the Person class to the question and I'll add an actual REPL transcript demonstrating my points while interacting with that class to the answer.

How could i make a reproducible example without knowing how it works, getting a working example is the point of my question. I provided a link to an example of what it return when i pass a simple expression to a function which is a True or False boolean. But you didn't check it because you have to create an account and i don't know where else to host it where you could access it without account.

A "reproducible example" needs to reproduce the problem, not a solution -- reproducing the code that unexpectedly returns [True] would be great. Questions are expected to be self-contained and answerable even with no links at all.

BTW, unless I'm mistaken, I think https://repl.it/ allows REPLs to be viewed without an account.

@CarlL, ...read the edit -- I added a concrete example of SQLAlchemy returning not True or False but an object that can be passed to where.

Thanks, you're example sort of put me on the way. I can see that the object used in the expression must be a sqlalchemy Column object for it to be received by the function as a converted sql string. Now i guess i just have to explore the source code of the Column class in sqlalchemy to try to understant what it must have to have this effect.

I pointed you in the relevant direction earlier -- the trick is to make the dunder methods invoked for your comparison operators to build AST-esque objects describing the operations to perform.

@CarlL Jumping back a few topics, re: "What returned object?" -- the object returned by <, >, ==, etc as overridden by Column.__lt__, Column.__gt__, Column.__eq__, etc. The default expectation is for those operations to return booleans, but Python doesn't enforce it, and SQLAlchemy takes advantage of that lack of enforcement.

@CarlL, ...so nothing "gets the OR from the expression", really; the expression just gets run, and the result of running it is an object that represents the knowledge that there needs to be an OR condition created in generated SQL, where the two branches combined with the OR do the specific operations required.

Wait you lost me, how does <, >, == return an object? That's what i don't understand, where is the expression transformed into object(s)? So i can reproduce this behavior.

Have you looked up "dunder methods"? Have you looked up (or do you have prior familiarity with) the special meaning of methods with the particular names I've been mentioning (__lt__, __gt__, __eq__, etc)? It's hard for me to know where to start without knowing your level of background.

If it's easier to start with an actual implementation, see https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/483edf651f6c3db6729f8d75265241b67ccd6b80/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py#L122

...is the missing piece knowledge that operator overloading exists at all? Something's clearly getting lost in translation, but I really don't know what. (See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.lt and other contents of the same page).

You we're right in the end operator overloading was what i needed, as long as the overloaded operator returns an object it is possible to get the entire expression passed as argument from within the function.

Not just "an object" in general, but specifically an object that records the operations that created it.
